# Segment tree built on "light bulbs"

Tags: algorithm, optimization, segment-tree

I have encountered following problem:
There are **n** numbers (0 or 1) and there are 2 operations. You can swich all numbers to 0 or 1 on a specific range(note that switching 001 to 0 is 000, **not** 110) and you can also ask about how many elements are turned on on a specific range.

Example:

```
->Our array is 0100101
We set elements from 1 to 3 to 1:
->Our array is 1110101 now
We set elements from 2 to 5 to 0:
->Our array is 1000001 now
We are asking about sum from 2nd to 7th element
-> The answer is 1
```

Brute force soltion is too slow(O(n*q), where q is number of quetions), so I assume that there has to be a faster one. Probably using segment tree, but I can not find it...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @itprorh66 I believe the problem statement is pretty clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build subsampling binary tree in the fashion of mipmaps used in computer graphics.

Each node of the tree contains the sum of its children's values.

E.g.:

```
0100010011110100
 1 0 1 0 2 2 1 0
  1   1   4   1
    2       5
        7
```

This will bring down complexity for a single query to O(log₂n).

For an editing operation, you also get O(log₂n) by implementing a shortcut: Instead of applying changes recursively, you stop at a node that is fully covered by the input range; thus creating a sparse representation of the sequence. Each node representing M light bulbs either

1. has value 0 and no children, or
2. has value M and no children, or
3. has a value in the range 1..M-1 and 2 children.

The tree above would actually be stored like this:

```
        7
    2       5
  1   1   4   1
 1 0 1 0     1 0
01  01      01
```

You end up with O(q*log₂n).

Comment: I have just realized that I have asked about a whole different thing. Your solution is sufficient to this problem. Thank you! I thing I should ask a new question instead of editing this one...